# Manually notify kendo-angular directive when using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm using the kendo-angular tooltip directive with ng-repeat like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things" 
     kendo-tooltip="tooltip"
     k-options="thingTooltipModel"
     data-thingname="{{thing.name}}>
</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="thingTooltipTemplate">
    <span>Thing Name: #= target.data('thingname') #</span>
</script>
```

As stated in the kendo-angular documentation, the kendo widget isn't notified when I update `things`, so the tooltip continues to display the initial data. Is there a way to manually tell kendo to re-read the data?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller's method Maybe you should put $scope.$apply(function(){//Your CODE for the Update})

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`k-rebind`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#updating-widgets-when-options-change):

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things" 
     kendo-tooltip="tooltip"
     k-options="thingTooltipModel"
     k-rebind="thing"
     data-thingname="{{thing.name}}>
</div>
```

That will destroy the old widget and create a new one.